# How does one calculate the profitability for a coin?

Tags: exchange-rate, mining-profitability

Given, a coin has difficulty `'d'`, an exchange rate `'x'/BTC` or `'X'/USD`, and given that my hardware can do `'y' MH/s` (scrypt), how would I determine the best coin that I could mine? Do I need to consider any other factors?

Comment: You can use [this website](https://www.multipool.us/index.php) to find out what is currently most profitable to mine.

Comment: Um, pick the one that maximizes `x*y/d`.

Comment: I don't really see how this question is "too broad". Both Nick and Nate gave a valid answer in just a sentence. (Which would make good answers.)